# Pandas apply lambda to the entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Can anybody explain me why this code should not work?

```
wordsCount = {}

def addWord(x):
    print(x)

df.apply(addWord(x))
```

It return the error: TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0') 
The dataframe df contains some None value in some cell. My intention is to apply a function to all non-None value.

Comment: `.apply()` expects a function, but you are passing it the return value by calling `addWord(x)`, which is None, since no return value is specified in the `addWord` function. Just pass `addWord` without the parenthesis.

Comment: Ok thanks. So now I discover than with apply I can only iterate over columns. What is I want to iterate over each element of the dataframe?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.DataFrame.applymap`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

```
df.applymap(addWord)
```